# Typing hear instead of here

Tags: psychology

Is there a technical term to denote when a person types here instead of hear or any other wrong word of a homonym pair--there for they're,etc.

Comment: In academia we call it a *typo* (I couldn't help myself)

Comment: Love your reply Alice D.